# How can I avoid getting duplicate paths from os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I have the following directory structure

```
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/RESOURCE_ID/YYYY/FY/DOCUMENT_ID
```

for example, one path might be

```
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28
```

where

```
RESOURCE_ID = 100045
YYYY = 2008
DOCUMENT_ID = 28
```

Note, DOCUMENT_ID is the last directory in the path - there will be files in the DOCUMENT_ID directory

I was trying to take inventory of this structure using the following code

```
def survey():
    magic_paths = []
    for (resource_id, dirname,filename) in os.walk('/mnt/type/split/v2/doc'):
        if resource_id:
            for (magic_path, dirname2,filename2) in os.walk(resource_id):
                 if len(magic_path.split(os.sep)) == 10:
                      magic_paths.append(magic_path + os.linesep)
    write_survey(magic_paths)
    x = len(magic_paths)
    return x
```

I am getting five copies of each path in my magic_paths list.  I have 1,500,000 paths, so I am getting 7,500,00 items in my list.

The first 1,500,000 are the unique values.  The next 6,000,000 consist of groups that are rooted on the RESOURCE_ID, repeated 4 times

```
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28 #obs_1
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/29 #obs_2
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/30 #obs_3
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31 #obs_4
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/1028/2008/FY/28   #obs_5 # see the new RESOURCE_ID
.
.   1,499,995 more unique values
.
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28 #begin of first repetition
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/29
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/30
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28 #begin of second repetition
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/29
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/30
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28 #begin of third repetition
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/29
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/30
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/28 #begin of fourth repetition
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/29
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/30
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31
/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/1028/2008/FY/28     #series of 4 repetitions based on RESOURCE ID 1028
```

There are various files in the directories and subs at each level, I just need to inventory the paths to the DOCUMENT_IDs.

I do not understand why the results are patterned as they are.  I believed that I was starting at RESOURCE_ID and finding only the directories that were 9 deep since splitting on os.sep gives me a list with ten items.

```
'/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY/31'.split(os.sep) = ['','mnt',type','split','v2','doc','100045','2008','FY','31']
```

In response to the questions in the comments

1. I believed that I was getting each RESOURCE_ID directory and then walking it. That the other items returned from the first os.walk (dirnames and filenames) would be ignored
2. I did not think os.listdir would work, I can make this work with glob but am worried about it eating my memory

Comment: Why are you walking each directory *twice*? You call `walk()` again.

Comment: Do you understand a difference between `os.listdir` and `os.walk`? Second one does recursion for you. Nested `walk()` calls looks very suspicious.

Comment: Also, please post actual code; the code you posted is not valid Python; the path is not a quoted string for example. With errors like that it is hard to make out what other errors you put into your post that are not in your real code. I am assuming `os.walk()` and `walk()` are the same function, but can't be sure.

Comment: Give me a minute, it is the code, you are correct os.walk() and walk() are the same - done I imported the path in my original code (it was a variable) and just forgot to quote here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk()` will *recursively* walk a directory structure. For each directory you encounter, you start *another recursive call*. So for every directory, you recursively walk that directory plus all nested directories. That includes nested directories. By kicking off a search for `/mnt/type/split/v2/doc`, `/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045`, `/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008`,  `/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008` and `/mnt/type/split/v2/doc/100045/2008/FY` paths, you produce 5 matches per document ID.

Call `os.walk()` just once:

```
def survey():
    magic_paths = []
    for (resource_id, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('/mnt/type/split/v2/doc'):
         if len(resource_id.split(os.sep)) == 10:
              magic_paths.append(resource_id + os.linesep)
    write_survey(magic_paths)
    x = len(magic_paths)
    return x
```

You may want to prune the search after finding a match; there is no point in searching through further subdirectories once you find a `DOCUMENT_ID` directory:

```
def survey():
    magic_paths = []
    for (resource_id, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('/mnt/type/split/v2/doc'):
         if len(resource_id.split(os.sep)) == 10:
              magic_paths.append(resource_id + os.linesep)
              dirnames[:] = []  # clear the subdirs list to stop further recursion here
    write_survey(magic_paths)
    x = len(magic_paths)
    return x
```

Comment: You are saying that when it throws off a resource_id directory that then automatically gets walked - forgive my language so all of the YYYY directories are then walked . . .  this helps me understand why wild cards are not built into os.walk - they are not needed, instead you test the output

Comment: @MartijinPieters - can you edit this to explain why I had exactly the 4 dupes in that particular order?

Comment: @PyNEwbie: `os.walk()` walks your tree depth-first and it depends on how deep your tree is how often you kick off another `os.walk()` for a given parent directory that leads to the same nested subdirectory. But given that there are 4 levels of nesting, you'd kick of `os.walk()` for each of the 4 parent directories for each match.

Comment: @MartijinPieters I am trying to be better about not making thanks comments but I can't stop myself - thanks this helped me understand the process.